# Want to create apps for google glass.

Tags: google-app-engine, google-glass

I want to create a new app from the beginning in eclipse using java.

I have android sdk, Google app engine, maven with my eclipse.

Then how I start?

Google quick start tutorial is little bit clumsy.

I just want to make a timeline card and want to pass value "Hello World".

Then want to view from my Google glass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** GDK Preview 11/19/13

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/index

**And Finally:** *here is how to hello world in Glass..*

- Create a basic hello world apk.
- Install the apk on glass by following [this link.](http://songz.quora.com/How-to-run-Android-Apps-on-Google-Glass)

---

The official GoogleGlassDevelopment kit is not yet available for all developers. But developers are developing in the following ways:

**Google Mirror Api:**

Can be developed using java, .net, php, ruby, python and google go. The developers can access the mirror API, and google servers will talk to the Glass.

[image]

This way, we cannot access the hardware features of the Glass. Mirror API is mainly to website kind of info.

**Android SDK:**

Developers can develop with android sdk version 15.(ICS) and run the app directly using the same tools(eclipse/ android studio). link

The hardware available:
[image]

All the above hardware can be used with the same api available in ICS and above, Except touchpad and the transparent display. For those API, we must wait till [GDK](https://developers.google.com/glass/gdk) releases.