# How to pass data from Normal Android app to Google glass app and viceversa?

Tags: android, google-glass

I have no idea on GoogleGlass just searching on it.
I have  checked below links but I think below links are deprecated and I am unable to find a way to pass the data.I have searched for more than 4 days but unable to find a way to pass the data.

[Want to create apps for google glass.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807026/want-to-create-apps-for-google-glass)

https://github.com/Scarygami/mirror-api

[how to connect Android phone with Google Glass for data sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023176/how-to-connect-android-phone-with-google-glass-for-data-sharing)

https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start

https://github.com/NathanielWaggoner/GoogleGlassBlutooth

I am refering above links, but I am confused about sharing the data between Normal Android App and Google Glass App and Viceversa.

Please help me on this.Thanks in Advance.